# TypeScript: Extend using Generic?

Tags: typescript, generics

**Problem:**

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to extend a generic.

**API's Items and Responses**

I am working with a API service that has multiple type of items, for example, this if item type is for **User**:

```
interface IUser {
  email: string;
  id: string;
  displayName: string;
}
```

When requesting from the API a specific item, the response is, for example, for **User**:

```
interface IUserResponse {
  '@odata.context': string;
  email: string;
  id: string;
  displayName: string;
}
```

When requesting from the API a list of items, the response is, for example, for **User**:

```
interface IUserResponseArray {
  '@odata.context': string;
  value: [ {
      email: string;
      id: string;
      displayName: string;
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

**API's Response for `IUser` [Non-Generic]**

Taking the two responses, both have the following base:

```
interface IResponseBase {
  '@odata.context': string;
}
```

Extending from this base, the `IUser` response interfaces refactored:

```
interface IUserResponse extends IUser, IResponseBase {}

interface IUserResponseArray extends IResponseBase {
  value: IUser[]
}
```

**API's Response Generic**

Next, because this API supports multiple type of items, the response interfaces should be made generic.

Doing a array of generic items, made `IUserResponseArray` generic:

```
interface IResponseArray<T> extends IResponseBase {
  value: T[];
}
```

**Problem `type name expected`**

How can I do the same to make `IUserResponse` generic. The following attempt in defining a generic is invalid, error hint from my IDE is `type name expected`:

```
interface IResponse<T> extends ???<T>???, IResponseBase {}
```

Comment: Will a type alias and an intersection work for you instead of an interface?  That is, `type IResponse<T> = IResponseBase & T`.  If not, can you show the use case where it doesn't work?

Comment: I can't quite work out where you're getting the error. Can you create a single code block with the generic bits and point to where the error is?

Comment: Is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUIGcAOB7ELCAITiOQG8AoZZAcgAE8ATOMOAOgQMgA8w6ALmRYwUUAHMA3FQC+VKqEixEKDNnyEIAQShQ4ATwA8AFQB8yCPwghmWNJlwEipctVoA3OABsArhGETAG0AXRl5RXBoeCQHDWcIUwsrSFt7EwAaOKctVxRqOSA) the [mcve]?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The error `type name expected` was came from the IDE I am using. My question, what am I missing to make this correct TypeScript handling of generic.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, that solution works perfect!